# Как правильно объединять данные которые используются разными классами и частями программы в C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Как правильно объединять данные в c# .net (asp.net/ просто.net) проектах?
Например: у меня есть три класса, которые используют (using System.Net;) одни и те же библиотеки. Как поступить по-канону? В какой файл их вынести, или оставить всё в main файле, в таком случае, как привязать все файлы-классы к main-файлу?

Comment: Давать рекомендации по коду, который вы не показали, смысла не имеет. Показывайте конкретный код с конкретным вопросом/проблемой

Comment: А зачем их выносить/объединять? Чем мотивируешься?

Comment: Мне кажется это последствия использования C++. В C# нет инклюдов и тому подобного. using в начале файла удобная, но не обязательная конструкция. Так что можете не переживать за то, что у вас в каждом файле объявлено использование библиотек. Это объявление нужно компилятору для того, чтобы вы могли использовать сокращенные имена классов (только имя) вместо полных (все пространства имен и имя через точку).

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону SOLID!

Comment: Посмотрите как обычно пишут, например на GitHub. Самое распространенное: Один cs файл = один класс. Файл называется точно так же как класс, это самое удобное.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы пришли в C# из C/C++, то имеет смысл рассмотреть как происходит подключение библиотек в обоих случаях.

В C/C++ для связи между файлами и библиотеками используется директива `#include`. Это инструкция прекомпиляции, т.е. выполняется до передачи текста основному модулю компилятора. Встретив такую инструкцию, прекомпилятор замещает встреченную директиву `#include`, текстом указанного в директиве файла. Поэтому и имеет смысл выносить подключения библиотек в какое-то одно общедоступное место.

В C# каждый тип является самостоятельной единицей компиляции, даже если использует библиотечные типы. Если требуется обратиться к библиотечному типу, можно использовать его полное имя. В таком случае `using` в начале файла не требуется, но текст становится менее читаемым. Особенно заметно, когда используются библиотеки с длинными названиями:

```
var principal = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(
    System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain);
```

Можно вынести общий префикс с помощью `using`:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
...
var principal = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
```

Действие конструкции `usyng <namespace>;` ограничено файлом в котором она указана и их нельзя вынести в отдельный файл.

Таким образом использование `usyng <namespace>;` в начале cs-файла само по себе существенно сокращает количество текста и улучшает его читаемость.

Необходимые библиотеки перечисляются в файле проекта, который который MSBuild использует при сборке проекта как источник данных для формирования команд компилятору.

---

Я сознательно не углублялся в тонкости и показал только принципиальные отличия, т.к. тонкостей и нюансов в обоих случаях хватит на отдельную главу книги, а увидеть и пощупать их все получится только при полностью ручной компиляции из командной строки, чем сейчас мало кто занимается даже в академических целях.